# Generate the names of the keys on a piano

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

[On a standard 88 key piano, each key has a scientific name.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies)

The first three keys are A0, B♭0, and B0. The keys then proceed through C1, D♭1, D1, E♭1, E1, F1, G♭1, G1, A♭1, A1, B♭1, B1, and start over again at C2. This continues up through B7, and the final key is C8.

Any flat can instead be written as a sharp of the preceding note, e.g. D♭4 can also be written C♯4. If necessary, you can write "D♭4" as "Db4".

Your program should build an ordered sequence (array, list, vector, etc.) containing the key names (as strings, symbols, or some similar data structure) in order.

Program length should be measured in *characters*, to avoid penalizing people who properly generate ♯ or ♭ rather than # or b. However, Unicode recoding is forbidden.

Comment: [Here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/print-the-sizes-of-intervals-inside-of-a-piece-of-music) is a previous question that might be useful, as it involves taking note names as input.

Comment: "Unicode recoding is forbidden." Can you edit the question to explain what that means, please?

Comment: I'd prefer having scoring by bytes, except in the case of ♯ and ♭ which count as one byte each.

Comment: @Chris: I think it may refer to putting a compressed byte sequence into a Unicode string and just decompressing that.

Answer (score 6):

### Bash shell script (58)

```
echo {8..0}{B,♭B,A,♭A,G,♭G,F,E,♭E,D,♭D,C}|rev|cut -b40-410
```

If you do not have `rev`, you can instead use `tac -rs.` at a cost of five characters.

[Bending the rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6278/universal-rule-bending-code-golf-solver), I can subtract thirteen characters (for a score of 45):

```
echo {8..0}{B,♭B,A,♭A,G,♭G,F,E,♭E,D,♭D,C}|rev
```

If you really need a bash array, add six characters to the score (for a score of 64):

```
a=(`echo {8..0}{B,♭B,A,♭A,G,♭G,F,E,♭E,D,♭D,C}|rev|cut -b40-410`)
```

Comment: Can you say more about `tac -rs`?  In GNU coreutils 8.23 (and 6.10), `tac -rs` (the same as `tac --regex --separator`) complains about `-s` missing an argument, and `tac -rs ""` says it cannot be empty.  I don't see a BSD version of `tac` (though BSD does have `rev`) to compare to.

Answer (score 5):

#### GolfScript, <strike>60</strike> 57 characters

```
"A BbB C DbD EbE F GbG Ab"88,{1$2<@2>1$+\{8%},@9+12/+}%\;
```

The snippet produces the following array (see [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OwoiQSBCYkIgQyBEYkQgRWJFIEYgR2JHIEFiIjg4LHsxJDI8QDI%2BMSQrXHs4JX0sQDkrMTIvK30lXDsKcAo%3D)):

```
["A0" "Bb0" "B0" "C1" "Db1" "D1" "Eb1" "E1" "F1" "Gb1" "G1" "Ab1" 
"A1" "Bb1" "B1" "C2" "Db2" "D2" "Eb2" "E2" "F2" "Gb2" "G2" "Ab2" 
"A2" "Bb2" "B2" "C3" "Db3" "D3" "Eb3" "E3" "F3" "Gb3" "G3" "Ab3" 
"A3" "Bb3" "B3" "C4" "Db4" "D4" "Eb4" "E4" "F4" "Gb4" "G4" "Ab4" 
"A4" "Bb4" "B4" "C5" "Db5" "D5" "Eb5" "E5" "F5" "Gb5" "G5" "Ab5" 
"A5" "Bb5" "B5" "C6" "Db6" "D6" "Eb6" "E6" "F6" "Gb6" "G6" "Ab6" 
"A6" "Bb6" "B6" "C7" "Db7" "D7" "Eb7" "E7" "F7" "Gb7" "G7" "Ab7" 
"A7" "Bb7" "B7" "C8"]
```

*Edit:* Changed from `" "/""*` to `{8%},` to remove space.

Comment: I'm kind of intrigued by GolfScript, but a bit confused.  Do you know of any tutorials that would help a beginner learn the language?  I've tried the tutorial on the official GolfScript web site and looked at several other pages retrieved on Google, but it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @MikeDtrick There are some Golfscript answers on this website that have explanations about how they work (e.g.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6058/3527). However, the best way to learn GS is to start coding something. Even better - try submitting a GS answer and you'll learn from the feedback you'll get :)

Comment: @MikeDtrick other commented examples: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166/3527, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172/3527

Comment: @w0lf Thank you for the resources!

Comment: @w0lf I know this probably isn't the proper place to ask a question, but I'm trying to code an answer for [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6576/finding-duplicate-balls-in-a-basket) question in GolfScript.  I have a work in progress for the question, but I wanted to get in touch with someone who is skilled in this area.  This is just practice, I won't post the answer if someone helps me out.  Sorry for being a pest.

Comment: @MikeDtrick I can't say I'm _skilled_, but I want to help you if I can. I've created a chat room for this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4361/discussion-between-w0lf-and-mike-dtrick

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <strike>95</strike> <strike>112</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>97</strike> 104 chars

Admittedly not very streamlined:

```
Take[Flatten@Table[# <> ToString@k & /@ 
Partition[Characters[" CDb DEb E FGb GAb ABb B"], 2], {k, 0, 8}], {10, 97}]
```

The Flat symbol, although it occupies a single character, is transcribed to SO as `\[Flat]` so I used the letter "b" here.

Output:

[image: keys]

```
Length@%
(* out *)
88
```

Comment: How do you count 95 chars?

Comment: I forgot to change the character count when I made a correction. It is now correct. (White spaces are there for legibility only, with the exception of those between quotes.)

Comment: I get 100 keys from this rather than 88, but I can't find a rule against that, so +1 :-)

Comment: Weird. I too had noticed the 100 keys, but couldn't find an error.

Comment: David, your comment made me look at this again.  The output is no longer agreeing with the picture you included.  It starts `"A0", "Bb0", " B0", " C0",` and furthermore `"C1"` doesn't occur until *after* "Db1", " D1"` etc. (Previously I thought the real keys were in order and there were extras interspersed.)  Sorry, but it's broken. :-(

Comment: You are right once again.  And here I was happy, thinking I had broken 100 chars.

Answer (score 4):

## Python <strike>103</strike> <strike>96</strike> <strike>94</strike> 78

```
[x+y for y in'0123456789'for x in'C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab A Bb B'.split()][9:97]
```

updated according to Ev_genus's suggestion

updated according to Howard's suggestion

Comment: **94** `[x+y for y in'0123456789'for x in['C','Db','D','Eb','E','F','Gb','G','Ab','A','Bb','B']][9:97]`

Comment: Maybe you can use `'C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab A Bb B'.split()`?

Comment: omg, really! **78** `[x+y for y in'0123456789'for x in'C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab A Bb B'.split()][9:97]`

Comment: @Howard yeah, i forgot about that

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby: <s>75</s> 71 characters

```ruby
[*?0..?9].product(%w{C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab A Bb B}).map{|a,b|b+a}[9,88]
```

(Base idea borrowed from [Matt's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6808).)

Comment: You can use `[*?0..?9]` which is a little shorter.

Comment: I felt that I am missing something there, but I completely forgot the splat. Thank you @Howard.

Answer (score 3):

### J, <strike>81</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>63</strike> <strike>62</strike> <strike>61</strike> 58 characters

```
_11}.9}.(_2]\,|:9#"0'C DbD EbE F GbG AbA BbB '),.12#1":i.9
```

Output:

```
A 0 
Bb0 
B 0 
C 1 
Db1 
D 1 
Eb1 
E 1
...
G 7 
Ab7 
A 7 
Bb7 
B 7 
C 8
```

Probably a bit of room for shortening here.

Answer (score 3):

## C (<strike>92</strike> 84 characters)

Not impressive, could be reduced further.

```
main(i){for(i=9;printf("%c%c%d\n","CDDEEFGGAABB"[i%12]," b b  b b b "[i%12],i/12),++i<97;);}
```

Using Dietrich Epp's suggestion :

```
main(i){for(i=9;printf("%.2s%d\n","C DbD EbE F GbG AbA BbB "+2*i%24,i/12),++i<97;);}
```

It produces the following output :

```
A 0
Bb0
B 0
C 1
Db1
D 1
Eb1
E 1
F 1
Gb1

... // lines skipped

Eb7
E 7
F 7
Gb7
G 7
Ab7
A 7
Bb7
B 7
C 8
```

Comment: Can shave off 6 characters: `main(i){for(i=9;printf("%.2s%d\n","C DbD EbE F GbG AbA BbB "+(i%12)*2,i/12),++i<97;);}`

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks! I shaved off two other characters.

Answer (score 3):

### *Mathematica*, 88

88 characters for 88 keys :-)

```
(Row@{#2,#1}&@@@Tuples@{0~Range~8,StringSplit@"C D♭ D E♭ E F G♭ G A♭ A B♭ B"})[[10;;97]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 105 chars

### - failing on size, so ended up aiming for a wtf different solution.

Probably only works on little-endian arch (e.g. intel) due to assumptions of treating int as small string...
Assumes C program is called with no arguments, i.e. that w=1

```
t=12352,f;
main(w){
  t=t&64?t>>8:(w=1+w%7,(w-3)%3?t<<8|98:t+(w==3));
  f=t<<8|w+64;
  puts(&f);
  f-14403?main(w):0;
}
```

Output:

```
A0
Bb0
B0
C1
Db1
D1
Eb1
E1
F1
Gb1
G1
Ab1
--lines skipped--
Bb7
B7
C8
```

### Edits

- -9 chars - removing some brackets and reorganising an 'if'
- -18 chars - code shuffling, sub 64 from w and pass as main arg
- -13 chars - Use 't' to carry state rather than 'f'

Comment: Really creative answer!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell: 72 chars

```
take 88$drop 9[p++show o|o<-[0..],p<-words$"C D♭ D E♭ F F♯ G G♯ A B♭ B"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure - 71 chars

```
(for[c(range 10)n["C""Db""D""Eb""E""F""Gb""G""Ab""A""Bb""B"]](str n c))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 57+1

Just dug this up, a nice golfing exercise.  Requires `-E` for `say` -- counted in score.

`say+(CDbDEbEFGbGAbABbB=~/(.b?)/g)[$_%12],$_/12%9for 9..96`

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 88 bytes

```javascript
(o=`C,Db,D,Eb,E,F,Gb,G,Ab,A,Bb,B`.split`,`)=>o.flatMap((x,i)=>o.map(n=>n+i)).slice(9,97)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchJDgIhEAXQ61TFL1vTCzrptoeVd2AQDQYpIsR4ezQu33vYt63@FUs7ZrmG7iVXSUEluRN1Em3OWBwWrA4rNuwOOyaHCbPDbFQtKTYDw3oUdUu2XWwh@iD@4/lD1mM@RGZVU/SBBgwn7kzM/Qs)